# Forward requests coming into port 80, for a particular link, to port 8080 locally

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, wampserver

I have 2 web forms, one coded using Java Servlets on glassfish (port 8080) and another using PHP on apache(port 80). But my office ITdept is refusing to open port 8080 to outside traffic.
How do I set up Apache such that requests coming in for the form with the servlets are directed to port 8080?
Thanks
TX
PS: Im using wamp

Comment: Offtopic, should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [ProxyPass directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) is how it's normally done.

```
ProxyPass /url/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/url/
```